# C#, Selenium WebDriver. При поиске XPath выдает исключение

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Выдает исключение при поиске XPath, не понимаю почему, уже даже пробовал искать, по CSSSelector, но все равно выдает ошибку:

OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@aria-controls='suggest - list - b97mugvw7vm']"}
(Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.164)"

Мой код:

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
namespace QA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var driver = new ChromeDriver("D:\\Project 1\\С#\\QA\\Driver");

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://yandex.ru/");

                IWebElement input = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@aria-controls='suggest - list - b97mugvw7vm']"));
                input.Click();    
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А в "suggest - list - b97mugvw7vm" точно надо пробелы?

Comment: И без пробелов пробовал все так же как и было

Comment: Не сразу заметил, это же яндекс, при каждой новой загрузке страницы, в поле ввода запроса меняется всё, что идёт после suggest-list-*

Answer (score -1):

Вот так работает:

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
namespace QA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var driver = new ChromeDriver("D:\\Project 1\\С#\\QA\\Driver");

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://yandex.ru/");

                IWebElement input = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@class,'mini-suggest__input')]"));
                input.Click();    
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня не работает